# Get the rows with the latest date for an ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table has multiple rows for each id, with a calculated score and the date the calculation was done. Simplifying, it looks like this:

| id | calc_score | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 82 | today |
| 1 | 53 | yesterday |
| 1 | 92 | last week |
| 2 | 23 | today |
| 2 | 60 | yesterday |
| 2 | 73 | last week |

I need a query that returns only today's scores for each ID. I tried various combinations of `group by` and `distinct on` but didn't get very far.

What's the best way for doing this?

Comment: select id, calc_score, date from table1 t1 where t1.date = (select date from table1 t2 where t1.id = t2.id order by date desc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PG has several ways.  A simple approach is window functions, row_number, rank, etc.

The following will answer the question in your `title`, to return the latest (last) row per id (by date), which is different than the body of your question.

```
WITH cte AS (
       SELECT t.*
            , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
         FROM scores
     )
SELECT * FROM cte
 WHERE rn = 1
;
```

This just picks the (latest dated) first row for each id based on the `date` column descending.  This also assumes the `date` column really contains `date` values or something orderable like a `date`.

To answer your question in the `question body`:

> I need a query that returns only today's scores for each ID

more strictly, we could also do this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM scores
 WHERE date = current_date
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only today's scores, then you could use a direct comparison if the date has no time component:

```
where date = current_date
```

Or for either dates or timestamps:

```
where date >= current_date and date < current_date + interval '1 day'
```

If you want the most recent row per id, you would use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
order by id, date desc;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I need it sorted by `calc_score` desc. I need to top scores at the top.